# How to check for multiple pattern matching in Perl

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

Is there a way I can avoid using this for multiple pattern checks?

Can I tore all the patterns in an array and check if it matches any pattern in the pattern array? Please consider the case when I have more than 20 pattern strings.

```
if(  ($_=~ /.*\.so$/)
  || ($_=~ /.*_mdb\.v$/)
  || ($_=~ /.*daidir/)
  || ($_=~ /\.__solver_cache__/)
  || ($_=~ /csrc/)
  || ($_=~ /csrc\.vmc/)
  || ($_=~ /gensimv/)
){
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Eric okay ..i am sorry for not having done that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can use Perl version 5.10, then there is a really easy way to do that.
Just use the new [smart match (~~)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) operator.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.1;

my @matches = (
  qr/.*\.so$/,
  qr/.*_mdb\.v$/,
  qr/.*daidir/,
  qr/\.__solver_cache__/,
  qr/csrc/,
  qr/csrc\.vmc/,
  qr/gensimv/,
);

if( $_ ~~ @matches ){
  ...
}
```

If you can't use Perl 5.10, then I would use [List::MoreUtils::any](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils#any).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::MoreUtils qw'any';

my @matches = (
  # same as above
);

my $test = $_; # copy to a named variable

if( any { $test =~ $_ } @matches ){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Note that smartmatch is now flagged as experimental, and it *will* be removed or changed without further notice. (Sounds like this will happen in 5.26.) The latter solution should be used regardless of your version of Perl.

Answer (score 4):

Another pre-Perl 5.10 option is [Regexp::Assemble](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3a%3aAssemble), which will take a list of patterns and combine them into a single regex that will test all of the original conditions at once.

Comment: This can be far more efficient, especially if the pattern is tested is against multiple values. Starting a regex match is actually fairly expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Your original code could have been written more nicely like this:

```
if(  /.*\.so$/
  || /.*_mdb\.v$/
  || /.*daidir/
  || /\.__solver_cache__/
  || /csrc/
  || /csrc\.vmc/
  || /gensimv/
) { ... }
```

That is because `$_ =~ /foo/` is the same as just `/foo/`. If you have Perl 5.10 or greater, I would do as Brad suggested and use the smart match operator.